# How to enable refunds for paypal adaptive payments?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to make refunds for adaptive payments and I get following Error in response: 'NO_API_ACCESS_TO_RECEIVER'

On this page 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation/
in documentation exists link to  Grant API permission, but looks like it obsolete, and I can't find any other information how to enable refunds, has anyone resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The receiver must provide you (primary receiver) access to the refund API. The PayPal document clearly states the following:

> Have made a Pay request for which payment you want to refund the
>   payment, or you must have received the part of the payment you want to
>   refund, and
>
> Have permission to make a refund on behalf of the receiver, unless you
>   are also the receiver; in other words, each receiver whose account is
>   the source of the refund must have granted you third-party access
>   permission to call the Refund API operation.